# Built Play Framework Successfully, $ Play command not found

Tags: playframework

The Play framework built sucessfully, however when I use the $ Play command in the Git Bash I get:

```
$ play
bash: play: command not found
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.1/install

Any idea on what I am doing wrong, per the official documentation is should be smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you have add the play installation path into the system environment variable. To check it, you can use the following command line in your terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

in my system, play is installed in the "/opt/play-1.2.5.6" directory, so the output is like that

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/play-1.2.5.6:/bin
```

If the directory of installation is not displayed, you should do the following things:

First, open your bash_profile which is located in your user directory. You can type the two command line in your terminal to find the file

```
cd ~
ls -al
```

Then, the .bash_profile is listed. If there is not, you can create the file by yourself with the following command

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/play-1.2.5.6" > ~/.bash_profile
```

If the file has been existed, just add the following command in the .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/play-1.2.5.6
```

Finally, open the terminal again, just type "play" command

Good luck with you.

Answer (score 2):

The play command is part of the sox package in ubuntu, so you have to install sox to use it:

```sh
sudo apt-get install sox
```